# CSV Export programmatically, issue with certain characters at the start of a word

Tags: c#, excel, csv

I have a facility to export simple data to a csv file. Everything is working perfectly unless there isn't a '-' as the first character of any field. It displays '#NAME?' in the cell and I know this is because excel sees this as formula gone wrong. Is there a way I can force excel to ignore this?

Comment: I will also add, i have read adding a single quote before the term will fix this but this appears in my export along the text.

Comment: Are you exporting from Excel? Or using Excel interop? Or something else?

Answer (score 0):

Wrap in double quotes and set import options in excel to treat columns in quotes as text

Answer (score 0):

If you want to open the document in Excel why not actually create an excel file with something like [NPOI](http://npoi.codeplex.com/).  You can then have two options, a true unexcel tampered with CSV export and an actual Excel export.